# Cell does not automatically reflect the result of a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

MS Excel 2010 is not updating formulas. For instance, I have this formula in cell `D2`:

```
=A2 + B2
```

If I put data in `A2` and `B2`, `D2` does not show the result.

However, if I enter values in cells `A2` and `B2` first **BEFORE** I enter the formula in `D2`, it shows the result, but the formula only seems to work "once." If I change the values in either `A2` or `B2`, `D2` does not get updated.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "if I first fix the value of cell A2 and B2"

Comment: Are you on automatic calculation mode: File > Excel Options > Formulas > Calculation options > Automatic?

Answer (score 3):

Are your Calculation Options set to Manual? If they are, set them back to Automatic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set Calculations to Automatic in Formulas > Calculation Options > Automatic for excel to update contents of formulas automatically.

If you don't want automatic calculations but want to trigger a calculation after values are changed press the "Calculate Now" button of F9.